# How do spin orientations change during adiabatic demagnetization of paramagnet?

Tags: quantum-spin, adiabatic

Suppose a paramagnetic solid is taken on the following cycle, where $B_1 > B_2$
[image]

(1)->(2)->(3)

I'm trying to explain what happens to occupation numbers in magnetic levels.

**Step (1)**
As $B_1$ increases to $B_2$, more spins get aligned due to the stronger field and entropy which is a measure of disorder falls. The occupation levels in +spin direction increase.

**Step (2)**
Opposite happens? Some spins revert back to random orientation.

**Step (3)**
As temperature is increased while B is fixed, there are more thermal fluctuations in the occupation levels?